# HTML - difference between iframe reload and parent reload

Tags: javascript, html

Inside "myIframe":

When I reload the Iframe, my javascript inside this page  is not executed:

**myIframe:**

```
alert("reloaded");
$('.selectedTab').click(function() {
     document.getElementById("myIFrame").contentDocument.location.reload(true);
});
```

But if I reload its parent page the javascript is reloaded.

```
parent.location.reload();
```

what is the difference between these two approachs? 
 
It is possible to reload an Iframe contain without passing by the parent page and without requesting the server, just "replay" with the data already got?

Comment: confused... Where is the javascript located? the javascript you've shown so far looks like the code that would exist on the parent page, which of course wouldn't re-execute unless you reloaded the parent page.

Comment: the javascript exists in the iframe as I mentioned

Comment: if it's in the iframe... how does `document.getElementById("myIFrame").contentDocument.location.reload(true);` target the iframe from inside the iframe?

Comment: Actually I want to reload the Iframe where I am.

Comment: Just do `window.location.reload(...)` when the script is within iframe.

Comment: This is what I want to have. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As Kevin B mentioned this seems to be an issue with the content location. Make sure the Iframe src is also served from the same domain as parent.

http://jsfiddle.net/55Ewm/ - seems to work fine for me.

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
   alert("reloaded");
   $('.selectedTab').click(function() {
       document.getElementById("myIFrame").contentDocument.location.reload(true);
   });
}
</script>

<button class="selectedTab">Reload Iframe</button>
<iframe id="myIFrame" src="/" />
```

Comment: In fact the 'button' is inside "myIframe"